# Make sure no duplicate directory paths exist

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, directory, data-manipulation

I'm writing a script wherein the user selects directories, which are then stored in an array property, so that they can be recursively crawled.

```
{
  "archives": [
    "C:\\AMD\\Packages",
    "C:\\Users",
    "C:\\Windows",
    "D:\\",
    "E:\\Pictures\\Birthday"
  ]
}
```

I obviously don't want to be storing duplicate paths or paths that are contained by other paths. For example, if the user were to select a new folder to add to the array, `E:\\Pictures`, then `E:\\Pictures\\Birthday` would be discarded and replaced by it since `E:\\Pictures` contains `E:\\Pictures\\Birthday`.

```
{
  "archives": [
    "C:\\AMD\\Packages",
    "C:\\Users",
    "C:\\Windows",
    "D:\\",
    "E:\\Pictures"
  ]
}
```

---

I know this can be done by parsing all of the values being considered (i.e. `['C:', 'AMD', 'Packages'], [...], ...` etc) and then comparing them all to one another. However, this seems extremely intensive, especially if the array of paths grows bigger and the directory paths are longer.

---

You could also do it by comparing the strings with `includes`. For example, if A includes B or B includes A, split them, and discard the one with a longer length.

```
for (const dir of dirs){
  if (newPath.includes(dir) || dir.includes(newPath)){
    if (newPath.split('\\') < dir.split('\\')){
      // remove dir from json object and replace it with newPath
    }
  } else {
    pathArray.push(dir)
  }
}
```

After reading one of the answers below, I just realized that the `includes` method runs into the issue of comparing similar, yet unique paths i.e. `C:\Users` and `C:\User`.

---

Although there's gotta be a better way to do this??

Comment: In your sample, the array ```archives``` is sorted alphabetically. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: @user753642 yeah, it's alphabetical in the example, but it doesn't have to be. i'm only concerned about not adding any "duplicate" paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will give you your desired results. It first looks to see if the parent of the path exists in the archives, and if so, does nothing. If it doesn't, it then removes any children of the path and then inserts the new path.

**Update**

I've added a `delim` input to the function to make it usable for unix/MacOS style filenames as well.

```js
let data = {
  "archives": [
    "C:\\AMD\\Packages",
    "C:\\Users",
    "C:\\Windows",
    "D:\\",
    "E:\\Pictures"
  ]
};

const add_to_archives = (path, data, delim) => {
  // does the parent of this path already exist? if so, nothing to do
  if (data.archives.reduce((c, v) =>
      c || path.indexOf(v.slice(-1) == delim ? v : (v + delim)) === 0, false)) return data;
  // not found. remove any children of this path
  data.archives = data.archives.filter(v => v.indexOf(path.slice(-1) == delim ? path : (path + delim)) !== 0);
  // and add the new path
  data.archives.push(path);
  return data;
}

add_to_archives("E:\\Pictures\\Too", data, "\\");
console.log(data);
add_to_archives("E:\\PicturesToo", data, "\\");
console.log(data);
add_to_archives("D:\\Documents", data, "\\");
console.log(data);
add_to_archives("C:\\AMD", data, "\\");
console.log(data);

data = {
  "archives": [
    "/var/www/html/site",
    "/etc",
    "/usr/tim",
    "/bin"
  ]
};

add_to_archives("/var/www/html/site2", data, "/");
console.log(data);
add_to_archives("/etc/conf.d", data, "/");
console.log(data);
add_to_archives("/usr", data, "/");
console.log(data);
add_to_archives("/var/www/html", data, "/");
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: im just going to bed, so ill have a look at this tomo morning. im curious, what do you make of the code example i just added to my question? talk tomo

Comment: @BugWhisperer What you posted seems reasonable as long as paths always begin with a drive specifier. Note that I'm in Oz so won't be awake when you get up, so I'll apologise in advance for any delay responding to you then.

Comment: After skimming through another answer below, I realized there's an issue with the `includes` approach since unique paths will still be discarded or ignored i.e. `C:\Users` and `C:\Users`.  It sucks because it seems like any effective approach is super intensive. FWIW, I would ultimately like an approach that works across Linux, MacOS, and Windows, and I'm not even sure how MacOS handles these sorts of things. I'll be thoroughly examining and comparing all of the answers later today since some random stuff in my schedule just popped up.

Comment: @BugWhisperer I've made an edit to my solution to allow it to work with Unix/MaxOS style filenames as well (basically adding a delimiter input to the function)

Comment: k, its gonna take me a little while to unravel your code :) what does the `, false` in the `if` conditional accomplish exactly? ive never seen that before o: oh wait nm its part of the data reduce function

Comment: is there a particular reason youre using reduce? are you using it for the accumulator or? i ask cuz it iterates through the whole archives array, even if a parent directory has already been found. i dont think my question was initially very clear or included as much detail as i should have included. basically the archives array is going to start out as an empty array, so there will never be a duplicate directory path due to checking for duplicates on every single user path selection

Comment: @BugWhisperer yes, I'm using it as an accumulator. As you say, it will iterate through the entire array even once a parent has been found; you could potentially improve that by just using a for loop with a break, but since the code is written as `c = c || ...` once `c` is true none of the other `indexOf` operations will actually happen, so it won't save that much time.

Comment: is there a particular reason you used the non-strict equals operator?

Comment: @BugWhisperer When comparing to `delim`? no. The only reason I used it for the result of `indexOf` is I'm used to other languages where that function returns both `false` and `0` so you need a strict compare.

Comment: i thought maybe because the `\\` is escaped the non-strict comparison mayve been required, but i guess not. im in the habit of always using strict comparisons whenever possible

Comment: @BugWhisperer no, definitely not required. I should probably be better about using strict compares, although I do like to take advantage of type juggling at times...

Comment: are you adding the trailing slash to avoid direct matches or for MacOS/UNIX or?

Comment: @BugWhisperer it's to ensure that something like /a/b/c doesn't match a/b/cd

Comment: ohhh right right of course. sorry. first time ever doing something like this

Comment: well done. holy smokes u sure packed a lot of moving parts into such a short amount of code. took me forever to understand exactly what was happening and why lol. its been a while since i worked with strings so i completely forgot theres also an `indexOf` on the string prototype. that threw me for a loop. appreciate your help man <3

Comment: its definitely an interesting problem. not gonna lie, when i first started dissecting your code i thought to myself "i could probably write my own function in less time than its going to take me to fully understand this" lol :D

Comment: one last question: any idea what the deliminators on Linux/MacOS are? is it purely slashes on linux?

Comment: @BugWhisperer linux is unix, so slash. MacOS these days is also based on Unix, and I'm pretty sure the delimiter is slash as well.

Comment: i guess ill have to do some more research regarding macos. thanks again buddy!!

Answer (score 1):

We can approach the problem by using a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

The purpose is to limit the number of paths we check for inclusion or "containment".

That approach may be useful if you have a lot of siblings (tree traversal + lookup as key for each folder). 
It is overkill if you often have a root folder specified in `archives`

#### algorithm

```
tree = {}
foreach path
    split the path in folders (one may iterate with substring but it is worth it?)
    try to match folders of that path while traversing the tree
    if you encounter a stop node, skip to next path
    if not, 
        if your path end on an existing node
            mark that node as a stop node
            drop the children of that node (you can let them be, though)
        else
            include the remaining folders of the path as node in tree
            mark the last node as a stop node
```

#### Implem

Note that implem below will fail if path includes a folder named "stop". By subjective order of preference

- Use `Map` and `Symbol('stop')`
- or a real tree (at least do not store folders alongside the boolean `stop`)
- do not suppose any stop node and always drop children if you manage to reach the end of your path
- Hope no one tries to outsmart you and rename `stop` as some obscure -folder will not exist- `lolol_xxzz9_stop`

```js
function nodupes(archives){
    tree = {};
    archives.forEach(arch=>{
        const folders = arch.split('\\');
        folders.splice(1,1);
        //case of empty string such as D:\\\
        if(folders[folders.length-1].length==0){folders.pop();}
        let cur = tree;

        let dropped = false;
        let lastFolderIndex = 0;
        let ok = folders.every((folder,i)=>{
            if(cur[folder]){
                if(cur[folder].stop){
                    dropped = true;
                    return false;
                }
                cur = cur[folder];
                return true;
            }
            cur[folder] = {}
            cur = cur[folder];
            lastFolderIndex = i;
            return true;
        });
        if(ok){
            cur.stop = true;
            //delete (facultatively) the subfolders
            if(lastFolderIndex < folders.length-1){
                console.log('cleanup', folders, 'on node', cur)
                Object.keys(cur).forEach(k=>{
                    if(k != 'stop'){
                        delete cur[k];
                    }
                })
            }
            
        }
    });
    //console.log('tree', JSON.stringify(tree,null,1));
    //dfs on the tree to get all the paths to... the leaves
    let dfs = function(tree,paths,p){
        if(tree.stop){
            return paths.push(p.join('\\\\'));
        }
        Object.keys(tree).forEach(k=>{
            dfs(tree[k], paths, p.concat(k));
        });
    }
    let paths = [];
    dfs(tree, paths,[]);
    return paths;
}
let archives = [
    'C:\\\\ab',
    'D:\\\\', //just some root
    'D:\\\\ab',//be dropped
    'D:\\\\abc',//dropped as well
    'F:\\\\abc\\\\e',//two folder creation
    'C:\\\\ab\\c',
    'B:\\\\ab\\c',
    'B:\\\\ab',//expect B\\\\ab\\c to be dropped
]
console.log(nodupes(archives))
```

Comment: commenting to myself. Actually dropping the children when end of folders is encountered may be preferable. I fail to see any downsides

Comment: im just going to take a thorough look at your answer right now

Comment: sorry i dont think i was entirely clear in my question. the `archives` property will start out as an empty array, and when the user selects folders, they will be added to the array so long as they or their parent isnt already present in the array. ive given you a vote up nonetheless. i had an idea after posting this question regarding how to go about it that was similar to the tree idea.

Comment: @BugWhisperer but as proposed you can restitute the array after everything has been added to the tree iteratively. Do you need to keep an array maintained during insertion? (this means when dropping paths, array will have to be shrinked and "compacted" because potentially multiple holes?)

Comment: what do u mean by re-situate it? so what im doing is saving the array in a `config.json` file. this array is used to load a list of paths when the program is launched. the list is also modified or likely modified when a user deletes and selects/adds new paths respectively. the list of paths in the array will be crawled recursively to look for particular files in those directories and this info will also be stored in another json file, say `data.json`, to easily obtain and display in the future

Comment: it is not re-situate it but restitute it idem give it back. If you look at implem (and run it) you can see you get back the array from the tree (corresponding to paths without dupplicates nor "containment". I would avoid maintening a tree _and_ an array. So either: save array (as per your requirement), load it to a tree, interact with the tree, then save the tree as an array. OR simply go for Nick or Henry and just consider an array. I would belive that the most time you waste is not in deleting paths but in crawling the paths recursively.. (memory vs fs interaction)

Comment: oh the crawling will most definitely be more intensive. still i want the loading/adding/deleting/managing as efficient as possible. so is this tree you talk of stored as a map or? im going to bed but ill check back tomo

Comment: the tree is stored in memory...as a tree. You save it (idem serialize it) as an array. And you rebuild it (like when you start your application) in memory (from your serialized array)

Comment: im so confused. are you talking about `localStorage`? what i mean is what `type` is the tree? [edit] i just realized youre using an object as the tree, but still confused as to what u mean by how your storing the tree?

Comment: I never said localStorage, so no. A tree by definition is a tree. You can use whatever classes you want to represent it. I chose not to write a class and simply took the built-in ```Object``` as you figured it out. Regarding the storage, how do __you__ store the array? I think my solution is maybe too abstract while very simple, maybe write it from scratch yourself, it will all come clear!

Comment: i will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
console.log([
    "C:\\AMD\\Packages", 
    "C:\\Users", 
    "C:\\User", 
    "E:\\Pictures", 
    "E:\\Pictures\\Birthday", 
    "C:\\Windows", 
    "D:\\", 
    "D:\\aabbcc", 
    "E:\\Pictures\\Birthday"
].sort().reduce(
    (acc, cur) => 
        acc.length > 0 
        && cur.startsWith(acc[acc.length - 1]) 
        && ( cur.indexOf("\\", acc[acc.length - 1].replace(/\\$/,"").length) !== -1  )
        && acc || acc.concat(cur)
    , []
))
```

Comment: The `archives` array will never ever have duplicate values in it to begin with. The question is all about preventing "duplicate" paths from being added or always discarding specific paths for more general paths that already contain the specific path. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I'll be thoroughly examining your answer when I have some more free time later today.

Comment: yeah took a look at your answer, and this doesnt even accept user input, so it really doesnt address my question